# get output parameters from WorkflowApplication

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I have a state machine workflow with two states 
- Employee Request
- Manager Approval

In Employee request I save the request to the database through code activity and genereate
a request number

How I get those outputs after calling WorkflowApplication.Run()

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup callbacks to WorkflowApplication actions:

```
WorkflowApplication Application;
//...
// Setup callbacks
this.Application.Completed += OnApplicationCompleted;
// Run the application
this.Application.Run();
```

Then implement OnApplicationCompleted like this:

```
void OnApplicationCompleted(WorkflowApplicationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CompletionState)
    {
        case ActivityInstanceState.Closed:
            // Application finished correctly
            // Get outputs
            var output1 = e.Outputs["NameOfOutput"];
            break;

        case ActivityInstanceState.Canceled:
            // Application was cancelled before completion
            break;

        case ActivityInstanceState.Faulted:
            // Application throw an exception and was shut down
            break;
    }
}
```

All of this is covered on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560894%28v=vs.110%29.aspx